# How to install eclipse PDT 3.1 in Eclipse Juno?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt, eclipse-juno

Using the following update sites:

- http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/
- http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.2/

Eclipse 4.2.0 Juno installs PDT 3.0.1.

The [nightly developer builds](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/downloads/), currently 3.1.1, can be installed through the update site:

- http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/3.1.1/nightly

**How can I install the stable version of PDT 3.1.0?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very possible that [you can't](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/366539/).

Comment: yeah, i got this error, if i try to select "Debug Config >> PHP Web Application" : "No tab group defined for launch configuration type org.eclipse.php.debug.core.launching.WebPageLaunch", so it seems so.

Answer (score 10):

Go to Help->Install new software and there put this url :

- http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno

Now in search for php and select those packets , push over next button and finalice the install. After that reset Eclipse-Ide and you will have the php plugin :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Choose PDT from the following link.
 http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/